# How to take the previous component in ionic 4 in Router and NAvControl

Tags: angular7, ionic4

I have used the previous URL using below codes, (Reference from:
https://community.wia.io/d/22-access-the-previous-route-in-your-angular-5-app)

```
 this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      this.currentUrl = this.router.url;
                    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                         this.previousUrl = this.currentUrl;
                          this.currentUrl = event.url;
                    }
        });
```

But I want to take the previous components similar like ionic 3(this.navController.getPrevious()). I could not find any methods in ionic 4

I have googled and searched the angular posts but unable to get the proper results. THanks in Advance.

Comment: did you sir find a solution for that , i have googled alot also but nothing.

Comment: No..  I could not find that one. I have changed the my applicaiton flow, instead of "Previous" taken "Current" and used

Comment: I started also to use "Current" , thanks alot for your response

Comment: you are using current route and send it as param to next page ?

Comment: Exactly. I have maintained the separate array of these navigations and passing to next page.